# PayPal API & MVC5: Get Price from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I'm trying to set up PayPal to accept payment from my site which calculate fees based on the number of photos they uploaded.  Followed a [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/870870/using-paypal-rest-api-with-asp-net-mvc), but I wanted to pass the price which I calculated in my other controller.

My PayPal controller:

```
public ActionResult PaymentWithPaypal()
    {
        APIContext apiContext = PayPalConfig.GetAPIContext();

        try
        {
            string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
            {
                string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Paypal/PaymentWithPayPal?";
                var guid = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000));                    
                var createdPayment = this.CreatePayment(apiContext, baseURI + "guid=" + guid);
                var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();
                string paypalRedirectUrl = null;
                while (links.MoveNext())
                {
                    Links lnk = links.Current;
                    if (lnk.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
                    {                            
                        paypalRedirectUrl = lnk.href;
                    }
                }

                Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
                return Redirect(paypalRedirectUrl);
            }
            else
            {               
                var guid = Request.Params["guid"];
                var executedPayment = ExecutePayment(apiContext, payerId, Session[guid] as string);
                if (executedPayment.state.ToLower() != "approved")
                {
                    return View("FailureView");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error" + ex.Message);
            return View("FailureView");
        }
        return View("SuccessView");
    }

    private PayPal.Api.Payment payment;

    private PayPal.Api.Payment ExecutePayment(APIContext apiContext, string payerId, string paymentId)
    {
        var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId };
        this.payment = new PayPal.Api.Payment() { id = paymentId };
        return this.payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
    }

    private PayPal.Api.Payment CreatePayment(APIContext apiContext, string redirectUrl)
    {
        var itemList = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() };
        itemList.items.Add(new Item()
        {
            name = "Participation Fee",
            currency = "USD",
            price = "5",
            quantity = "1",
            sku = "sku"
        });

        var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };
        var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
        {
            cancel_url = redirectUrl,
            return_url = redirectUrl
        };            
        var details = new Details()
        {
            tax = "1",
            shipping = "1",
            subtotal = "5"
        };            
        var amount = new Amount()
        {
            currency = "USD",
            total = "7", 
            details = details
        };

        var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
        transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            description = "Transaction description.",
            invoice_number = "your invoice number",
            amount = amount,
            item_list = itemList
        });

        this.payment = new PayPal.Api.Payment()
        {
            intent = "sale",
            payer = payer,
            transactions = transactionList,
            redirect_urls = redirUrls
        };
        return this.payment.Create(apiContext);

    }
```

Controller where my price is calculated:

```
        int Asection;
        int Bsection;
        int Csection;
        int Dsection;

        if (viewPhotos.GetA1.Any() || viewPhotos.GetA2.Any() || viewPhotos.GetA3.Any() || viewPhotos.GetA4.Any())
        {
            Asection = 1; 
        }
        else
        {
            Asection = 0;
        }

        if (viewPhotos.GetB1.Any() || viewPhotos.GetB2.Any() || viewPhotos.GetB3.Any() || viewPhotos.GetB4.Any())
        {
            Bsection = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Bsection = 0;
        }

        if (viewPhotos.GetC1.Any() || viewPhotos.GetC2.Any() || viewPhotos.GetC3.Any() || viewPhotos.GetC4.Any())
        {
            Csection = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Csection = 0;
        }

        if (viewPhotos.GetD1.Any() || viewPhotos.GetD2.Any() || viewPhotos.GetD3.Any() || viewPhotos.GetD4.Any())
        {
            Dsection = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Dsection = 0;
        }

        int TotalSection = Asection + Bsection + Csection + Dsection;

        viewPhotos.MoneyValue = TotalSection;

        int RequiredMoney;
        if (TotalSection == 1)
        {
            RequiredMoney = 20;
        }
        else if (TotalSection == 2)
        {
            RequiredMoney = 25;
        }
        else if (TotalSection == 3)
        {
            RequiredMoney = 30;
        }
        else
        {
            RequiredMoney = 36;
        }

        viewPhotos.RequiredMoney = RequiredMoney;

        return View(viewPhotos);
```

My view where price was shown to user:

```
<p>You will need to pay participation fees USD @Model.RequiredMoney.</p>
<h3>Total: USD @Model.RequiredMoney</h3>
@Html.ActionLink("Make Payment with PayPal", "PaymentWithPaypal", "Paypal")
```

So far the above codes work with the default testing item price and detail on the site. Would appreciate if anyone could help to show how do I set the amount to be collected by PayPal to my calculated price, without any shipping or tax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The _sample_ is creating hard coded data for "items" in its `CreatePayment` function. You'll have to wire up your user's selected items to it. In other words, replace the hard coded items in `CreatePayment` accordingly. Hth.

Comment: Hi @EdSF, I understand what you're saying, but I don't know how to achieve it. Would you be so kind to demonstrate or share a relevant tutorial on it? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't ever inline `new Random()` like you're doing as you can easily have circumstances where the result is not random. You should always create a single static variable for `Random` and simply re-use that wherever you need it.

Comment: Thank you @Enigmativity for your comment. I'm pretty new to this whole thing and the reason my project is still running was entirely due to the tutorial which I was following, so I have no idea what can be replaced if not Random(). But I'm also a bit concerned with what you mentioned, hence I've added the current userID followed by Random() as the guid to reduce the probability of duplication. I hope that would lower the risk of going into error.

Comment: @Eva - No, it wouldn't. You need to move the `new Random()` out to a field level variable, i.e. `private static Random rnd = new Random();`. Then you just use `rnd` whenever you were otherwise using `new Random()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and reviewing the log for a while, here's how I solved my problem:

At the controller where I calculated my price, I used TempData to store my price:

```
TempData["ParticipationFee"] = RequiredMoney;
```

Then at the PaypalController, under `CreatePayment` function,

```
var itemList = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() };

string FeeAmount = TempData["ParticipationFee"].ToString();

itemList.items.Add(new Item()
{
    name = "Participation Fee",
    currency = "USD",
    price = FeeAmount,
    quantity = "1",
    sku = "sku"
 });
```

Hit F5 and got a successful response from Paypal Sandbox. Woot!